# JS loop through array and group with map

Tags: javascript, loops

I have array `terms`:

```
[
    {
        "label": "programming",
        "id": 6,
        "taxonomy": "category"
    },
    {
        "label": "design",
        "id": 4,
        "taxonomy": "post_tag"
    },
    {
        "label": "css",
        "id": 3,
        "taxonomy": "post_tag"
    },
    {
        "label": "other",
        "id": 8,
        "taxonomy": "category"
    }
]
```

I am trying to create the following `newArray` array from array `terms`:

```
[
  {
      "taxonomy": "category",
      "ids": [6, 8]
  },
  {
      "taxonomy": "post_tag",
      "ids": [4, 3]
  },
]
```

I have to take the `id` from each object in the `terms` array and add them to the corresponding taxonomy in the array `newArray`.

I am trying the following:

```
const taxonomyArray = [];
const newArray = [];

// Loop through original term array and get the taxonomies
terms.forEach( el => {
   taxonomyArray.push( el['taxonomy'] )
});

// Remove duplicate taxonomy values from array taxonomyArray
const uniqueTaxonomyArray = [ ...new Set(taxonomyArray) ];

// Create the new array
uniqueTaxonomyArray.forEach( el => {
    const groupedArray = terms
    .filter( ( { taxonomy } ) => taxonomy === el )
    .map( ( { value, taxonomy } ) => ( {
       taxonomy: el,
       ids: value
    } ) );

    newArray.push( groupedArray );
});
```

It is giving me:

```
[
    [
        {
            "taxonomy": "category",
            "ids": 6
        },
        {
            "taxonomy": "category",
            "ids": 8
        }
    ],
    [
        {
            "taxonomy": "post_tag",
            "ids": 4
        },
        {
            "taxonomy": "post_tag",
            "ids": 3
        }
    ]
]
```

Is there a better way to achieve this?

Comment: Use `flatMap` instead of `forEach`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Array.reduce` with `Map`

```js
const terms = [ { "label": "programming", "id": 6, "taxonomy": "category" }, { "label": "design", "id": 4, "taxonomy": "post_tag" }, { "label": "css", "id": 3, "taxonomy": "post_tag" }, { "label": "other", "id": 8, "taxonomy": "category" }];

const map = terms.reduce((acc, {id, taxonomy}) => {
  if (acc.has(taxonomy)) {
    acc.get(taxonomy).ids.push(id);
  } else {
    acc.set(taxonomy, {taxonomy: taxonomy, ids: [id]});
  }
  return acc;
}, new Map());

const result = [...map.values()];

console.log(result);
```

[reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce)

> The reducer walks through the array element-by-element, at each step
> adding the current array value to the result from the previous step
> (this result is the running sum of all the previous steps) — until
> there are no more elements to add.

```
// Arrow function
reduce((previousValue, currentValue) => { ... } )
reduce((previousValue, currentValue, currentIndex) => { ... } )
reduce((previousValue, currentValue, currentIndex, array) => { ... } )
reduce((previousValue, currentValue, currentIndex, array) => { ... }, initialValue)

// Callback function
reduce(callbackFn)
reduce(callbackFn, initialValue)

// Inline callback function
reduce(function(previousValue, currentValue) { ... })
reduce(function(previousValue, currentValue, currentIndex) { ... })
reduce(function(previousValue, currentValue, currentIndex, array) { ... })
reduce(function(previousValue, currentValue, currentIndex, array) { ... }, initialValue)
```

Comment: Thank you! This looks like it is working great. What does `acc` stand for?

Comment: @CyberJ it's accumulative result from each reducing step.